# In PostgreSQL, how can I extract matching items from a list?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, filter

I have a query in PostgreSQL that returns results like this, records with a string and a json array:

```
id   | property_list
-----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"i1" | [{"a":{"b":"no"}}, {"a":{"b":"yes"}}, {"a":{"b":"true"}}, {"a":{"b":"false"}}]
"i2" | [{"a":{"b":"yes"}}, {"a":{"b":"no"}}, {"a":{"b":"no"}}]
```

What I need is something like this:

```
id   | yes_or_true
-----+------------
"i1" | 2
"i2" | 1
```

I need to count the properties in `property_list` where `a.b` equals "yes" or "true".

There are more properties, but there is always an `a.b` property with a string as its value.

I can solve this using a PL/pgSQL function, but for some reason, I'm in a situation where I can't use a PL/pgSQL function. How can I solve this in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  (SELECT count(*)
    FROM json_array_elements(property_list) el
    WHERE el->'a'->>'b' IN ('true','yes')
  ) AS yes_or_true
FROM the_table
```

Answer (score 0):

A lateral join to `jsonb_array_elements()` will solve this:

```
with indat (id, property_list) as (
  values 
    ('i1', '[{"a":{"b":"no"}}, {"a":{"b":"yes"}}, {"a":{"b":"true"}}, {"a":{"b":"false"}}]'::jsonb), 
    ('i2', '[{"a":{"b":"yes"}}, {"a":{"b":"no"}}, {"a":{"b":"no"}}]'::jsonb)
)
select id, count(*) filter (where jdat->'a'->>'b' in ('yes', 'true'))
  from indat 
 cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(property_list) as j(jdat)
 group by id;

 id | count 
----+-------
 i1 |     2
 i2 |     1
(2 rows)
```